# Formatting the Array in PHP as required output given in the example

Tags: php, arrays, json

i have an php array as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [price_with_discount] => 2025.00
            [sales_date] => 2014-09-02
            [sales_type] => 1
            [part_id] => 6
            [part_number] => SN14FW-KU027OR03
            [part_rate] => 2025.00
            [sales_status] => 2

            [product_name] => Ladies Fashion Wear 
            [model_number] => Bamboo Shawl Natural
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [price_with_discount] => 1700.00
            [sales_date] => 2014-09-02
            [sales_type] => 1
            [part_id] => 23
            [part_number] => SN14FW-KU015PL01
            [part_rate] => 1700.00
            [sales_status] => 2

            [product_name] => Ladies Fashion Wear 
            [model_number] => Allo Cotton Shawl
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [price_with_discount] => 1850.00
            [sales_date] => 2014-09-02
            [sales_type] => 1
            [part_id] => 31
            [part_number] => SN14FW-KU022GR06
            [part_rate] => 1850.00
            [sales_status] => 2

            [product_name] => Ladies Fashion Wear 
            [model_number] => Bamboo Stole 
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [price_with_discount] => 1840.00
            [sales_date] => 2014-09-03
            [sales_type] => 1
            [part_id] => 49
            [part_number] => SN13FW-KU113BR02
            [part_rate] => 1840.00
            [sales_status] => 2

            [product_name] => Accessories
            [model_number] => Bangle
        )
)
```

I want to format given array into json something like below, I want them to be categorized by the product_name field given in the array. I did tried but i was nowhere near to that result.
I tried my code is below:

```
foreach ($reports as $report) {
            $product_name = str_replace(' ', '_', trim($report->product_name));

                $r[$product_name][] = array(
                        'part_number' => $report->part_number,
                        'part_rate' => $report->part_rate,
                    ); 

        }

        $reports = json_encode($r,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

But i want as below:

```
{
    "Data":[
    {
        "ProductName":"Ladies_Fashion_Wear",
        "ProuuctItems": [
            {
                "part_number": "SN14FW-KU027OR03",
                "part_rate": "2025.00"
            },
            {
                "part_number": "SN14FW-KU015PL01",
                "part_rate": "1700.00"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "ProductName":"Accessories",
        "ProuuctItems": [
            {
                "part_number": "SN14FW-KU030GR02",
                "part_rate": "2040.00"
            }
        ],
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Your PHP array holds no information about any product_items as i shown in the desired JSON output.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far. Also, you have to *explain* how you want the original array to be transformed into JSON (they are obviously not the same). We do not care what you **want**; if you want an answer you have to put some effort into it and ask an actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing here is that, you just need to use the `$report->product_name` as your key and make it a multi dimentional again on setting the new array, and then finally, just encode it. Example:

```
$r['Data'] = array();
foreach($reports as $report) {
    if(!isset($r['Data'][$report->product_name])) {
        // initial insertion
        $r['Data'][$report->product_name] = array(
            'ProductName' => $report->product_name,
            'ProductItems' => array(),
        );
    }
    // push it inside once created
    $r['Data'][$report->product_name]['ProductItems'][] = array(
        'part_number' => $report->part_number, 
        'part_rate' => $report->part_rate
    );
}

// simple reindex
$r['Data'] = array_values($r['Data']);
echo '<pre>';
$final = json_encode($r, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $final;
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ONj01d)

Answer (score 0):

Use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

It's pretty self-explanatory

Edit:
Before encoding to JSON you can consolidate your array. You'll need to use your desired value as key.

Code example:

```
$result = array();

foreach($source as $item) {
    $product_name= key($item);
    $other_attributes = current($item); // repeat for all other attributes

    if(!isset($result[$product_name])) {
        $result[$product_name] = array();
    }
    $result[$product_name][] = $other_attributes ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**json_encode** will convert any given value (except a resource) into a JSON value:

```
json_encode(array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5));
```

would return:

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

In your case you are looking to convert an array of Objects of type StdClass

You might want to consider making your class implement **JsonSerializable** (php 5.4 upwards)
and create a method **jsonSerialize** which would output each of your objects in the desired array format.

example :

```
public function jsonSerialize() {
        return array('ProductName'=>'myName','productItems'=>array('part_number'=>'123456'))
    }
```

more info : http://php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php